# Conditional Concatenation for Exchange Contact Imports

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, concatenation

*CSV contains fake information

`Python on Kaggle w/ Pandas + Numpy`

Context:
Goal is to import/update Exchange contacts. Users want to search for parent email by their student(s).

Input (see CSV screenshot):

> ```
>  - 'Student ID' column (7-digit number)
>  - 'Parent ID' column (7-digit number)
>  - 'Student First Name' column (str)
>  - 'Student Last Name' column (str)
>  - 'Parent First Name' column (str)
>  - 'Parent Last Name' column (str)
> ```

Desired Output (see CSV screenshot):

> ```
>  - 'Contacts' column
>  *'Contacts' column follows this pattern:
>       - One Student: "studentLastName, studentFirstName (parentLastName, parentFirstName)"
>       - Multiple Students: "studentLastName, student1FirstName, student2FirstName, & student3FirstName (parentLastName,> parentFirstName)"
> ```

[image: Input CSV]

Assumptions:

> - use student/parent IDs to evaluate conditions
>
>   - Many students/guardians share last names and are not related
>   - Many students have >2 guardians
>   - Many students do not share last names with one or more guardians
>   - Some students are siblings with different legal last names

#1. What I tried: Nested for loop with an if statement

```
for i in range(14):
    for j in range(14):
        if contacts.iloc[i]['parentID'] == contacts.iloc[j]['parentID'] and i!=j:
            hold = [contacts.iloc[i]['studentFirstName'], contacts.iloc[j]['studentFirstName']]
    print(hold)
```

#What I was expecting: list of tuples of student first names of siblings where the corresponding `parentIDs` match in different rows

#Example Output:

```
[[Uganda, Tiramisu], [Uganda, Tiramisu], [Ethernet, Persimmon], [Ethernet, Niagara], [Persimmon, Niagara]]
```

#I am new to DataFrames. I want to treat everything like lists.

#2.What I tried: Nested for loop with `numpy.where()`:

```
for i in range(14):
    for j in range(14):
        print(i, j)
        print(contacts.iloc[i]['parentID'], contacts.iloc[j]['parentID'])
        np.where(contacts.iloc[i]['parentID'] == contacts.iloc[j]['parentID'],
                    print(contacts.iloc[i]['studentFirstName'] + ' and ' + contacts.iloc[j]['studentFirstName']), print('1'))
```

#What I was expecting: `student1FirstName` and `student2FirstName` where `parentIDs` match, else `1`

#I don't understand broadcasting, and feel like that and/or printing results is breaking this.

#Considering alternatives: `pd.agg(), pd.groupby(), lambda functions, list comprehension`

#I am a beginner to `Pandas/Numpy/Python`. When practicing I think more easily with for loops, then try to convert them to list comprehension. It seems there are many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think this is a difficult problem to solve, but some inputs are missing.  2 suggestions.  1) provide the expected output; 2) provide code to replicate the test data.  Also, If the use case is to group students by parent email, add parent email as a field?

Comment: 1) Expected output is 'Contacts' column in the screenshot above. I want to populate that column automatically for a much larger data set. I manually entered that as an example. 2) The 'code to replicate the test data' is my goal. I have more information in the original CSV, but my assumption is to use Parent ID and Student ID because they don't change. Often parents will change their emails, sometimes their names become anglicized. Thank you for your suggestions, I appreciate your time.

Comment: I have a working solution based on your groupby answer below, I will post that and delete this comment soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of what you are asking for:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Student ID': [1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 10, 10, 22, 22],
    'Parent ID':  [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 3,  4,  3, 4],
    'Student First Name': ['Native', 'Native', 'Uganda', 'Uganda','Uganda','Tiramisu', 'Tiramisu', 'Tiramisu', 'Ethernet', 'Ethernet', 'Persimon', 'Persimon', 'Niagra', 'Niagra'],
    'Student Last Name': ['Americans', 'Americans', 'Socrates', 'Socrates','Socrates','Socrates', 'Socrates', 'Socrates', 'Regression', 'Regression', 'Regression', 'Regression', 'Regression', 'Regression'],
    'Parent First Name': ['Femur', 'Gigantic', 'USBC', 'Lei','Expo','USBC', 'Lei', 'Expo', 'Monitor', 'Isopropyl', 'Monitor', 'Isopropyl', 'Monitor', 'Isopropyl'],
    'Parent Last Name': ['Americans', 'Peanut', 'Socrates', 'Socrates','Socrates','Socrates', 'Socrates', 'Socrates', 'Chocolate Chips', 'Bits n Bits', 'Chocolate Chips', 'Bits n Bits', 'Chocolate Chips', 'Bits n Bits'],
    'parent_email': ['Femur.A@email.com', 'Gigantic.P@email.com', 'USBC.S@email.com', 'Lei.S@email.com', 'Expo.S@email.com', 'USBC.S@email.com', 'Lei.S@email.com', 'Expo.S@email.com', 'Monitor.C@email.com', 'Isopropyl.B@email.com', 'Monitor.C@email.com', 'Isopropyl.B@email.com', 'Monitor.C@email.com', 'Isopropyl.B@email.com']
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Group parent emails by students
grouped_emails = df.groupby(['Student ID', 'Student First Name', 'Student Last Name'])['parent_email'].apply(list).reset_index()
grouped_emails.to_excel("grouped_emails.xlsx", index=False)

# Display grouped emails
print(grouped_emails)
```

[image]